# Проблема с 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.7

Задача - вывести средний балл для каждого класса. Но python выдаёт:

```
File "main.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(middle_class("9a"))
  File "main.py", line 21, in middle_class
    for grade in grades[x['scores']]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

```
        grades = [
            {"school_class" : "9a" , "scores" : [5, 3, 4, 5, 5]},
            {"school_class" : "9b" , "scores" : [4, 4, 5, 2, 2]},
            {"school_class" : "9c" , "scores" : [3, 2, 5, 3, 5]},
            {"school_class" : "9d" , "scores" : [2, 3, 4, 5, 5]}
        ]


        def middle_class(class_number):
            if class_number == "9a":
                x = 0
            elif class_number == "9b":
                x = 1
            elif class_number == "9c":
                x = 2
            elif class_number == "9d":
                x = 3


            grade2 = 0


            for grade in grades[x['scores']]:
                grade1 = grade
                grade2 += grade1
            middle_class = grade2/5
            return middle_class


        print(middle_class("9a"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так должно работать:

```py
grades = [
            {"school_class" : "9a" , "scores" : [5, 3, 4, 5, 5]},
            {"school_class" : "9b" , "scores" : [4, 4, 5, 2, 2]},
            {"school_class" : "9c" , "scores" : [3, 2, 5, 3, 5]},
            {"school_class" : "9d" , "scores" : [2, 3, 4, 5, 5]}
        ]


def middle_class(class_number):
            if class_number == "9a":
                x = 0
            elif class_number == "9b":
                x = 1
            elif class_number == "9c":
                x = 2
            elif class_number == "9d":
                x = 3


            grade2 = 0


            for grade in grades[x]['scores']:  # Поменял место скобки
                grade1 = grade
                grade2 += grade1
            middle_class = grade2/5
            return middle_class


print(middle_class("9a"))
```

Ошибка была в том, что Вы перепутали место квадратной скобки. Скорее всего, это просто опечатка, но у Вас получалось, что Вы пытались обратиться к числу, как к словарю, вместо того, чтобы сделать это число одним из ключей словаря.